# How to perform a button action using a outlet colletion?

Tags: iphone, ios

Not sure how to word this correctly but I currently have:

```
    - (IBAction)revertTint:(id)sender {
    for (UISegmentedControl *swItem in allSegmentCollection) {
        int selectedSegment = swItem.selectedSegmentIndex;
        swItem.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
        if (selectedSegment !=-1)
        {
            [swItem setTintColor:nil];
        }
    }   
}
```

and have wired up each button from storyboard to this action and it works fine, but my question is can I just have it perform this action using the outlet collection rather than wiring up all the control segments to this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IBOutletCollection` is used for referring to a group of UI items collectively. I don't think you can use it to configure their target and action in the XIB / storyboard, but you can have a loop in your code which iterates the items and sets the target and action. Usually the collection would be used for grouping the items such that the can be enabled/disabled or shown/hidden together (or a similar task).